# How do I import/reference/require a transpiled TypeScript file?

Tags: typescript1.7

I have created a `myLib.min.js`/`myLib.d.ts` file combination from my TypeScript project using AMD module type, ES5 target and TypeScript 1.8 `--outFile` parameter. The `--outFile` parameter results in concatenating all the transpiled `.js` into one single `myLib.js` file and a corresponding `myLib.d.ts` file.

The two generated files `myLib.min.js`/`myLib.d.ts` are supposed to be deployed.

Now I want to utilize my deployment in another TypeScript project. I'm using `SystemJS` to load the modules and a web page to host the loader.

The JavaScript on the web page is supposed to only load `main.min.js`. `main.min.js` is then supposed to load `myLib.min.js`.

Here's the HTML I'm using in my web page:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.baseURL = "../output";
        System.import("/tests/Scripts/main.min.js");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: **What am I to add to `main.ts` to have the transpiled code load `myLib.min.js`?**

In my *VS Code* environment, if I'm using `import {MyClass} from "path/to/myLib"` at the top of `main.ts` I'm getting an error message telling me that "'path/to/myLib.d.ts' is not a module".

If, however, I'm using a `/// <reference path="path/to/myLib" />` at the top of `main.ts` all the symbols from the lib are not getting recognized and red squiggles are displayed whenever I'm trying to reference a class name from my library.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the export keyword for MyClass in your myLib.ts. [Here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules) is a good read to start with Modules.

```
export class MyClass{
        //parameters and functions here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, Seshu. I have had a very enlightening discussion with the TypeScript team at GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6382 , solving my question already.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer from the TypeScript team, for public reference:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6382